# Insert from select in Cursor - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert, cursor

I was wondering if anybody could help me with this SP, I dont know why, but the procedure only insert the first result (about 20 lines) of the select inside de Insert statement. Im doing something wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_tine_tb_temp_month`$$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `db_sumarizados`.`sp_tine_tb_temp_month`()

    BEGIN
  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b DATE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT SITE_NE_NAME, DATE FROM unl_tb_ecl_stat_hh WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30' GROUP BY SITE_NE_NAME, DATE HAVING COUNT(*) < 24;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows := TRUE;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sitios_elegidos (
  SITE_NE_NAME CHAR(16), FECHA DATE, HORA TIME
  );

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO a, b;

    IF no_more_rows THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO sitios_elegidos (SITE_NE_NAME, FECHA, HORA) SELECT SITE_NE_NAME, FECHA, HORA FROM time_intervals i LEFT JOIN tb_de_pruebas p ON i.fecha = p.DATE AND i.hora = p.TIME WHERE SITE_NE_NAME = a AND DATE = b;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;

 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET no_more_rows = FALSE;
```

...right before...

```
END LOOP;
```

Otherwise, if your `INSERT ... SELECT` finds nothing, it is probably prematurely tripping your `CONTINUE` handler and setting the value to `TRUE` before the cursor is actually exhausted.